# "Status Pending" from chrome.instanceID within a Chromebook Kiosk App

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I've got some problems with google cloud messaging. I am currently developing an Chromebook app but got some problems with retrieving the token from the instanceID(https://developer.chrome.com/apps/instanceID#method-getToken). I use this to verify the authenticity of the app that is used back on a server. The token is verified by the server based on a Api key that is only know by the server and GCP. For a couple of days this code worked, but today I  received a “pending status” message back. This way the app got stuck in a loop because it does not get a token from the entity.

We created a second entity and tested if the app is having the same problems, but with the new entity id it is receiving a token. Are there any limits how many calls can be made on one IP address?
In the Google Cloud Platform we currently not seeing any max quota’s all the values are zero.

Below there is the code we use in the app.

```
function getTokenFromIID(launchData, win, callback) {
 chrome.instanceID.getToken({
    "authorizedEntity": "863321080232",
    "scope": "GCM"
 }, function(instanceId) {
    callback(launchData, win, instanceId);
 });
}
```

And the callback function. In the else statement we apply some code to the created window.

```
function applyWindow(launchData, win, tokenId) {
 if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
     console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
     getTokenFromIID(launchData, win, applyWindow)
 } else {
     // Continue code
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance